# Remove leading zeros from a field if any else put as it is. Bind Variable not declared

Tags: sql, oracle

Im trying to access the fields using loop variable, I'm getting log message

Bind Variable "loop_emp" is NOT DECLARED
anonymous block completed

It is run on ORACLE ENGINE.

I'm trying to write a plsql routine to remove leading zeroes if present from the values of a field of a table and put it in a temp table and if no leading zeroes then put the value as it is.

```
create table temp_ref1(locality_id number(9),post_code varchar2(25));



DECLARE
  v_sal   NUMBER;
  str     VARCHAR2(255);
  str1     VARCHAR2(255);
BEGIN
  FOR loop_emp IN
  (select * from ref_locality_post_cods where locality_id in (select locality_id from invalid_pc_and_loc_comb1))
  LOOP
    str :='select substr(post_code,0,1) from ref_locality_post_cods where locality_id = '||:loop_emp.locality_id;
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE str into v_sal;
      IF (v_sal = '0') THEN
        str1 := 'insert into temp_ref1 values('|| loop_emp.locality_id ||', ltrim('|| loop_emp.post_code ||',0) )';
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE str1;
      ELSE 
          str1 := 'insert into temp_ref1 values('|| loop_emp.locality_id ||','|| loop_emp.post_code ||' )';
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE str1;
  END IF;
  END LOOP loop_emp;
END;

select * from temp_ref1;
```

The routine should convert the data from ref_locality_post_cods to

```
loca..  postc... 
30    0221
110   230
271   0872
281   872
281   0873
```

op/

```
loca..  postc... 
30    221
110   230
271   872
281   872
281   873
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a `ltrim` function

```
ltrim(loop_emp.post_code,'0')
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove colon in front of `:loop_emp` in `str := 'select ...`

By the way, why using that much of dynamic SQL? Can't you do that in a *static* manner?

```
declare
   v_sal  varchar2 (255);                                        -- not NUMBER
   str    varchar2 (255);
   str1   varchar2 (255);
begin
   for loop_emp
      in (select *
            from ref_locality_post_cods
           where locality_id in (select locality_id
                                   from invalid_pc_and_loc_comb1))
   loop
      select substr (post_code, 0, 1)
        into v_sal
        from ref_locality_post_cods
       where locality_id = loop_emp.locality_id;

      if (v_sal = '0')
      then
         insert into temp_ref1
              values (loop_emp.locality_id, ltrim (loop_emp.post_code, '0'));
      else
         insert into temp_ref1
              values (loop_emp.locality_id, loop_emp.post_code);
      end if;
   end loop loop_emp;
end;
```

Comment: if you clean up the code, than you can also remove a select inside a loop and do `substr` direct :)

Comment: better => one insert with ltrim in a loop.. no need to do  select und if

Comment: @hotfix: Or, even better - avoid PL/SQL completely. Couldn't that be done in a single INSERT statement?